# Paragraph at the center of the remaining page (horizontally and vertically)

Tags: java, alignment, itext

I need to create PDF file using iText. At the first page there should be a header at the top of the page, and then a document title exactly at the center of the remaining page area (horizontally and vertically).

Googled a lot, the best solution I've found is to create a table and use its cell aligning methods. The problem is: to use vertical alignment properly, I need to set cell's minimum height (cell.setMinimumHeight(...);) But I don't know how much height is remaining! Using document.getPageSize ().getHeight () with some hard-coded offsets does not look like a good option - I don't want to change this hardcode any time I change font sizes, etc.

Here's the code of the "header" at the top of the page, if it is important:

```
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
Paragraph o = new Paragraph("test", headerFont);
o.add(new LineSeparator(1, 100, Color.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, -5));
preface.add(o);
o.add(new Paragraph(" "));
document.add(preface);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's what I've got so far...

```
public static float getAvailableHeight(PdfDocument pdfDocument) {
    Float indentBottom = pdfDocument.bottomMargin();
    try {
        Method method = pdfDocument.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("indentBottom");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        indentBottom = (Float) method.invoke(pdfDocument);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    float offset = pdfDocument.top() - pdfDocument.getVerticalPosition(false);
    return pdfDocument.getPageSize().getHeight() - offset - pdfDocument.topMargin()  - indentBottom
            - pdfDocument.bottomMargin();
}
```

Works for me. Hope this will help someone else.

You'll need access to the PdfDocument object which is encapsulated inside PdfWriter. I just made my own CustomPdfWriter which extends PdfWriter.

The ugly part with reflection is needed because method indentBottom() is package local in PdfDocument class.